# How to write an sql statement that selects a number of rows with specific IDs?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a table that I would like to select a number of rows from using one sql statement.  is this possible? If so, please could someone help me with the syntax for such a statement?  I was going to retrieve the rows separately in a foreach loop (PHP).

```
// PHP
 $USER_ID = user_2
 $arraySearchRecords = [id_2, id_21, id_54, id_543];

 foreach($arraySearchRecords as $docId){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE userId='$USER_ID' AND documentId='$docId' LIMIT 1";
     $result = $MYSQLI -> query($sql);

 }
```

Comment: just read mysql WHERE IN()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implode your array as comma separated values like "id_2","id_21","id_54","id_543" and use IN clause

```
$clause = implode(",",$arraySearchRecord);
$clause = rtrim(",",$clause); //this will remove the last , that remains in the string 

$sql="SELECT * from myTable WHERE documentId IN ($clause)";
```

This will retrieve all the records that match one of the values in the in clause

See [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html) for more details

This way you don't need to iterate the array with the loop and repeat the query several times

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the steps:**
**1.** Create string from array $arraySearchRecord using implode.
**2.** Use [**WHERE IN()**](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-in) clause to search more than one condition.

```
   <?php
      $USER_ID = user_2
      $condition = implode(',',$arraySearchRecord);
      $condition = rtrim(',',$condition); //used to remove the last
      $sql='SELECT * from myTable WHERE userId = "$USER_ID" AND documentId IN ($clause)';
      $result = $MYSQLI -> query($sql);
   ?>
```